# sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24

Tags: c

I have a C application running on Linux and it processes thousands of messages...but not whe I run the application after a couple minutes it brings up the following error:

sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24

The application is doing about 30 messages per seconds, could it be some file open handle issue?

STDOUT receives: "Process 19374 received signal 11 "

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help ;-)

Lynton

Comment: signal 11 means segmentation fault. Try using a debugger, e.g. gdb ("man gdb" for help). Not sure about the libc error. How many processes does the application start? Is process 19374 a sub process? Can you list the processes running ("ps aux | grep <yourapplicationname>") before and after the application crashes? What is the order of the error messages (comes the "cannot open shared object file" before "process 19374 received signal 11"?)

Comment: Make sure you aren't leaking file descriptors. `lsof -p <PID>` can tell you what you've got open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Errno 24 means: "Too many open files".
After some thoughts I think the application opens a file, which is not allowed by the system anymore. The application can not handle this situation correctly, and crashes with a segmentation fault. Are the return values from the "open" system call checked correctly everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

To handle this situation, I found 2 ways to resolve it. Either to work on same alloted file descriptor number or close FD just after their work have been done.